# Error trying to run Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Coded UI tests in Chrome

Tags: visual-studio-2012, selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests

I seem to have everything installed properly but still getting an error.

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException: The playback engine could not find Selenium binaries on your system. You need to install both the Selenium .NET bindings and Selenium Chrome driver to run cross browser coded UI tests.

1) Using VS2013 Ultimate 11.0.51106.01 Update 1

2) d/l and ran CodedUITestCrossBrowserSetup.msi

3) chromedriver comes up manually using version 26.0.1383.0

4) copied SeleniumDotNET files to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\Cross Browser Selenium Components"

Looked at all the docs I could find.  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled all the add-ons including VS2012 Update 2 CTP and it is now working for me.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

If this file doesn't exist, create a dummy one:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\Cross Browser Selenium Components\castle.core.dll

**Long version**

I couldn't get VS2012 Premium Update 2 (not CTP) working with 'Selenium components for Coded UI Cross Browser Testing' from here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/11cfc881-f8c9-4f96-b303-a2780156628d

The Visual Studio testing code in this dll:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\11.0\UITestExtensionPackages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.dll

... looks for this file:
....\Cross Browser Selenium Components\castle.core.dll

... but it doesn't exist.

To fix the problem, create any old file called castle.core.dll in the 'Cross Browser Selenium Components' folder. For my machine, I just created a zero length file called castle.core.dll it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and have added the castle.core.dll like Andrew suggested (just the new zero length file in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\Cross Browser Selenium Components) and it started to work.